# C# implementation of Z85 encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii85

Is anyone aware of a C# implementation of the [Z85](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:32) character encoding specification?
I have found the C/C++ library by [artemkin](https://github.com/artemkin/z85), but would like a native C# library if one exists.

Comment: Looks easy to implement.. you could write your own! Unfortunately, questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes I'm thinking that is what I'm going to do. Sorry, is there a good location for a question such as this?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.. Good luck with your implementation!

Comment: For anyone getting here, some examples:
https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/Ascii85.cs
https://github.com/coding-horror/ascii85/blob/master/Ascii85ConsoleSolution/Ascii85.cs

Comment: I also added my own implementation to Nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cromulent.Encoding.Z85/